# Browser is launching for headless chrome capybara with Selenium webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara, headless

I'm trying to launch chrome in headless but the browser keeps on launching. Tried several different ways

1. used chrome options and added arguments
2. used chrome capabilities as well

My chrome version: 86
OS - ubuntu
capybara - 3.32.2

First Helper file:

spec_helper.rb

```
Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome,
                                 options: Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: %w[headless no-sandbox disable-gpu]))
end

Capybara.default_driver = :headless_chrome
Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
```

Second try of Helper file:

```
Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app, 
    browser: :chrome,
    desired_capabilities:Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
       chromeOptions: {
                       args: %w[headless disable-gpu disable-popup-blocking no-sandbox]
                      }
           )
  )
end

Capybara.default_driver = :headless_chrome
Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is to not register your own driver and just use the one provided by Capybara

```
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless
```

Note - this will only work if you're not using rails system tests (no indication in your question that you're using rails though) since they override these settings - see the rails/rspec system test docs (`driven_by`) for that.

Comment: I am not using rails but still its launching chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by adding chromeOptions separately and had to remove `--` from all arguments

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, for Selenium >= 3.8, you have to specify `goog:chromeOptions` instead of `chromeOptions`.

So in your example:

```
...
Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
   "goog:chromeOptions": {
                   args: %w[headless disable-gpu disable-popup-blocking no-sandbox]
                  }
       )
)
```

I was experiencing the same issue and this solved it for me.